# Is it possible to use a CloudFront domain name as the custom origin for another CloudFront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to be able to configure many domain names with CloudFront distributions that all use the same CloudFront distribution as the custom origin. Lets say this common distribution has a domain name of `abdefgh12345.cloudfront.net` and it points to an s3 website.

```
type in example1.com > CloudFront for example1.com > abdefgh12345.cloudfront.net > s3website
type in example2.com > CloudFront for example2.com > abdefgh12345.cloudfront.net > s3website
type in example3.com > CloudFront for example3.com > abdefgh12345.cloudfront.net > s3website
```

The problem I am experiencing is that when going to `example1.com` in the browser, it 301 redirects using the `abdefgh12345.cloudfront.net`. I would like it so that the search bar doesn't change and it just shows `example1.com`

Comment: Why not use route 53 ALIAS?

Comment: Why would you do that? All this should be done from your DNS provider, such as Route53.

Comment: The main reason would be to attach SSL certs to the distributions for each custom domain